# SQL Server : update not updating table c# no error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to update a table of items:

```
public void updateDatabase(Item item)
{
    string sqlString = "UPDATE Items Set Quantity = '" + item.Quantity.ToString().Trim() + "' " + "WHERE ItemID = '" + item.ItemID.Trim() + "'";
    //string sqlStringParam = "UPDATE Items Set Quantity = @quant WHERE ItemID = @id";

    //Create & execute the update command
    using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(sqlString, mainConn))
    {
        //sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quant", item.Quantity);
        //sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", item.ItemID);
        Console.WriteLine(sc.CommandText.ToString());
        UpdateDataSource(sc, table);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("done");
}
```

This sends the command to the database class to execute the query:

```
protected bool UpdateDataSource(SqlCommand command, string table)
{
    bool success;

        try
        {
            if (mainConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                mainConn.Open();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(command.CommandText);

            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Console.WriteLine(command.ExecuteNonQuery());

            mainConn.Close();
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace, "Error Updating Database");
            mainConn.Close();
            success = false;
        }
        finally
        {
        mainConn.Close();
        }
    return success;
}
```

As you can see I've tried both the concat method and the paramaterized method, both won't update the table. Here is the output when trying to update 2 items:

```
UPDATE Items Set Quantity = '4' WHERE ItemID = '1122'
UPDATE Items Set Quantity = '4' WHERE ItemID = '1122'
1
done
UPDATE Items Set Quantity = '9' WHERE ItemID = '1155'
UPDATE Items Set Quantity = '9' WHERE ItemID = '1155'
1
done
```

To me, it seems like it should be updating the table. I've even run an exact copied statement from above as a single query and it updates the table.

The `ExecuteNonQuery` even returns a 1.

Comment: I am curious why you commented out the **correct** way to compose SQL?

Comment: I can change it back haha, overall both lead to the same outcome

Comment: Does the mainconn have a transaction by any chance? Try runing a 'select' in the code right after the update and see if you are getting the updated value...

Comment: Did you verify that the code is connecting to the correct database server and the database?

Comment: well if your quantity and ID's are integers why are you using the ' marks around them, forces sql to use implicate conversions

Comment: To see if the issue is with `mainConn` try refactoring your code to use a self contained connection similar to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @ChinaSyndrome They are strings into nvarchars

Comment: @JonP Hi Jon, I have added the block you have sent, the select statement returns the updated values as it needs to be. The problem is when the program is reopened, the valued are reset to how they were before the update, I feel as if the program isn't sealing off the transaction

Comment: @muratgu I have added the select statement as Jon and yourself suggested and it returns the correct updated values

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trace, just make sure you have SQL Server Profiler already installed in your system.

A SQL Trace will tell you which commands are executing on real-time within SQL server.

**SQL Server Profiler**

1. File - New Trace then choose server, Authentication Mode provide UserName and Password and click connect.
2. In the trace properties go to events selection tab.
3. click **Show all events** and **Show all columns**.
4. Click *Column Filters* button
5. click DatabaseID
6. click Equals then input the DB ID generated before in the Mangement Studio
7. Click Ok then click the **Run** Button

Enable the trace and then execute your application and voila!

This is going to help you in the future working with SQL server ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem had to do the property of the .mdf database file I was working with. It was set to 'Copy Always' rather than the correct 'Copy if new' setting. Funnily enough I was told for this assignment I HAD to use Copy Always, but that seems to be incorrect.

Thanks everyone for helping